# C faster way to check if a directory exists

Tags: c, performance, mkdir, opendir

I'm using opendir function to check if a directory exists. The problem is that I'm using it on a massive loop and it's inflating the ram used by my app.

What is the best (fastest) way to check if a directory exists in C? What is the best (fastest) way to create it if doesn't exists?

Comment: Silly question, are you calling `closedir()` afterwards?

Comment: And the faster way might be to do it asynchronously, but you should consider the capabilities of your media. If it is regular HDD then it might fail into seek-storm and this will work slow. But if you use RAID/SSD or even working in the cloud, this will work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could call `mkdir()`. If the directory does not exist then it will be created and `0` will be returned. If the directory exists then `-1` will be returned and `errno` will be set to `EEXIST`.

Comment: With the caveat that `ENOENT` may occur if something along the path doesn't exist as well.

Comment: True. Should have mentioned that.

Comment: Since you want to create the directory if it doesn't exist: yes. You save a ``stat()`` call.

Comment: Note that you need to include <sys/stat.h> (for `mkdir`) and <errno.h> (to handle `errno` and `EEXIST`).

Comment: @ckruse : If the directory exists in 99 % of cases, and if `stat` is faster than `mkdir` (which I don't have a clue about), your statement may not be true.

Comment: Note however that if you DON'T WANT to create the directory (but only check for existence, per first half of the question), then then `mkdir` costs you I/O (might be synchronized, costing an even greater hit in I/O performance for other actors on the system) and might fail for reasons unrelated to existence such as current account's permissions, mount options (R/O FS), or available filesystem space or quota.

Answer (score 50):

Consider using [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stat). `S_ISDIR(s.st_mode)` will tell you if it's a directory.

Sample:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

...
struct stat s;
int err = stat("/path/to/possible_dir", &s);
if(-1 == err) {
    if(ENOENT == errno) {
        /* does not exist */
    } else {
        perror("stat");
        exit(1);
    }
} else {
    if(S_ISDIR(s.st_mode)) {
        /* it's a dir */
    } else {
        /* exists but is no dir */
    }
}
...
```

Comment: how faster does it is comparing with opendir?

Comment: That depends on the operating system and the number of entries there are in the parent directory. It will be faster in any way and that's what `stat` is made for.

Comment: Would lstat also be an option?

Comment: @cwd , yes, I think `lstat` would possibly be the even better option because it does not follow symlinks. Depends on what is wanted though...

Comment: I am using this to test for "D:\path\subpath" and I've created the directory. It is telling me the dir does **not** exist. :/   *(using Windows/MinGW)*

Answer (score 21):

I prefer using [`access()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access)

```
if (0 != access("/path/to/possible_dir/", F_OK)) {
  if (ENOENT == errno) {
     // does not exist
  }
  if (ENOTDIR == errno) {
     // not a directory
  }
}
```

If you ensure a trailing `/` in the directory name, this works perfectly.

Comment: Could you point me to where you found the bit about the trailing slash? The `access()` man page does not seem to say anything about it.

Comment: This is the best reference I could find: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11

Answer (score 3):

I would use `stat()`, if available.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a memory leak.  Calling opendir should not inflate the RAM of your app as long as you remember to always call closedir after successfully opening a directory.  Also, make sure you are freeing any buffers you allocated to compute the directory name.

Comment: Yeap I'm closing it, I'll just use stat, thanks for your time!