# How can I check if a directory exists?

Tags: c, linux, directory

How can I check if a directory exists on Linux in C?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C faster way to check if a directory exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314586/c-faster-way-to-check-if-a-directory-exists)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a directory exists in Unix (system call)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828192/checking-if-a-directory-exists-in-unix-system-call)

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You can use [`opendir()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) and check if `ENOENT == errno` on failure:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>

DIR* dir = opendir("mydir");
if (dir) {
    /* Directory exists. */
    closedir(dir);
} else if (ENOENT == errno) {
    /* Directory does not exist. */
} else {
    /* opendir() failed for some other reason. */
}
```

Comment: If the folder does not exists, then how can I create one right away after confirming it does not exists?

Comment: In case you're using Visual Studio, `dirent.h` isn't available, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530933/dirent-h-in-visual-studio-2010-or-2008) for alternatives

Answer (score 58):

Use the following code to check if a folder exists. It works on both Windows & Linux platforms.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const char* folder;
    //folder = "C:\\Users\\SaMaN\\Desktop\\Ppln";
    folder = "/tmp";
    struct stat sb;

    if (stat(folder, &sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)) {
        printf("YES\n");
    } else {
        printf("NO\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the included headers are sufficient, for Linux at least?

Comment: S_ISDIR is only for POSIX, not Windows, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238918/s-isreg-macro-undefined)

Answer (score 19):

You might use `stat()` and pass it the address of a `struct stat`, then check its member `st_mode` for having `S_IFDIR` set.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

...

char d[] = "mydir";

struct stat s = {0};

if (!stat(d, &s))
  printf("'%s' is %sa directory.\n", d, (s.st_mode & S_IFDIR)  : "" ? "not ");
  // (s.st_mode & S_IFDIR) can be replaced with S_ISDIR(s.st_mode)
else
  perror("stat()");
```

Comment: I was wondering about `S_IFDIR` vs `S_ISDIR` and found this on the `stat` man page: _"POSIX.1-1990 did not describe the S_IFMT, S_IFSOCK, S_IFLNK, S_IFREG, S_IFBLK, S_IFDIR, S_IFCHR, S_IFIFO, S_ISVTX constants, but instead demanded the use of the macros S_ISDIR(), etc. The S_IF* constants are present in POSIX.1-2001 and later."_

Comment: `(s.st_mode & S_IFDIR)  : "" ? "not "` You seem to have mixed up the `?` and `:`

Answer (score 11):

The best way is probably trying to open it, using just `opendir()` for instance.

Note that it's always best to try to *use* a filesystem resource, and handling any errors occuring because it doesn't exist, rather than just checking and then later trying. There is an obvious race condition in the latter approach.

Answer (score 4):

According to [man(2)stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) you can use the S_ISDIR macro on the st_mode field:

```
bool isdir = S_ISDIR(st.st_mode);
```

Side note, I would recommend using Boost and/or Qt4 to make cross-platform support easier      if your software can be viable on other OSs.

Answer (score 4):

You may also use `access` in combination with `opendir` to determine if the directory exists, and, if the name exists, but is not a directory. For example:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* test that dir exists (1 success, -1 does not exist, -2 not dir) */
int
xis_dir (const char *d)
{
    DIR *dirptr;

    if (access ( d, F_OK ) != -1 ) {
        // file exists
        if ((dirptr = opendir (d)) != NULL) {
            closedir (dirptr); /* d exists and is a directory */
        } else {
            return -2; /* d exists but is not a directory */
        }
    } else {
        return -1;     /* d does not exist */
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: nice one, but I would change `int xis_dir (char *d)` to `int
xis_dir (const char *d)` as d is not modified.