# find directory in a C program

Tags: c, linux, directory, find

How can I find if a directory exists or not in a C program? I know that `getcwd()` gives you the current directory but I want to find ANY directory. Is there a function for that or how do I do it? I am using **Ubuntu**

Comment: What OS are you using?? Filesystem-API is OS-dependent

Comment: This might be of help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314586/c-faster-way-to-check-if-a-directory-exists

Comment: `man opendir`, `man stat` (of course, if you are using UNIX-based OS).

Comment: Why do you not do some research before posting?

Answer (score 1):

`opendir`, `readdir` and `closedir` are POSIX functions, so they should be available in Linux, MacOS, Windows as well as any Unix type system.

Answer (score 0):

you can use access() function , like for example:

access(path, F_OK);

It returns 0 if found. -1 if not found.

Answer (score 0):

```
int mkdir (const char *filename, mode_t mode)
```

you need to include the header file sys/stat.h to use this function.

The mkdir function creates a new, empty directory with name filename. The argument mode specifies the file permissions for the new directory file.A return value of 0 indicates successful completion, and -1 indicates failure.

In case of failure and if your Directory already exists errno value will equal to EEXIST.