# CLIPS: to check path to the directory

Tags: clips

CLIPS has function "(open)" used for opening files. If file can be opened this function returns "true". Is there a similar function for opening directories? I want to check that path to the directory (saved in the string variable) is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a similar function for opening directories. You would have to add one to the CLIPS source code using the user-defined function API described in the CLIPS Advanced Programming Guide. I couldn't find any references for a relevant library function in ANSI C, so you'd have to check for the appropriate function for whichever platform you're using:

[How can I check if a directory exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12510874/how-can-i-check-if-a-directory-exists)

[C faster way to check if a directory exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314586/c-faster-way-to-check-if-a-directory-exists)