# How should I use OPENDIR function?

Tags: c

I would like to check the existance of a directory. I recive just "yes" even though the directory doesn't exists. what should I do? Thank you very much!

```
int main()
{
if(opendir("dsfdsgfdsgrs") == NULL)
   printf("%s","no");
else
   printf("%s","yes");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314586/c-faster-way-to-check-if-a-directory-exists

Comment: You should store the results of `opendir` into a variable so you can call `closedir`

Comment: Copy and pasted your code, works for me.

Comment: Do you have `#include <dirent.h>` in your program?

Comment: Yes.  And `#include <sys/types.h>`

Comment: Yes, the problem was that with close.  Thank you everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    DIR *dir;

    dir = opendir("folder");
    if (dir == NULL) {
        printf("Couldn't open dir\n");
    } else {
        printf("Opened dir\n");
    }

    if (dir != NULL)
        closedir(dir);
}
```